# document.getElementById("algo").value; no detecta el input aunque el documento html ya haya cargado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Estoy intentando acceder al input de un cuestionario pero document.getElementById("algo").value me está devolviendo una cadena vacía.

Este es el archivo **submit_event.html**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/submit_event.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("#header").load("header_organization.html");
        $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <!-- Submit form -->
    <div class="form">
        <form class="event-form">
            <input class="normal" id="title" type="text" placeholder="title"/>
            <input class="normal" id="date" type="date" placeholder="date"/>
            <input class="small" id="hour" type="text" placeholder="hour"/>
            <input class="small" id="place" type="text" placeholder="place"/>
            <textarea id="brief_description" placeholder="brief description" rows="2" ></textarea>
            <textarea id="detailed_description" placeholder="detailed description" rows="6" ></textarea>
            <input class="normal" id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="contact email"/>
            <input class="normal" id="contact_phone_number" type="text" placeholder="contact phone number"/>
            <a class="standard_text">Upload a cover image </a>
            <input class="normal" id="imageUrl" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"/>
            <button id="publish_button">publish </button><br>
            <button id="cancel_button">cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el archivo **submit_event.js** [UPDATED]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Load the header and executes onHeaderLoad()
  $("#header").load("header_organization.html", onHeaderLoad);
});

//FUNCTIONS -- FUNCTIONS -- FUNCTIONS -- FUNCTIONS -- FUNCTIONS

//Executed after the header is loaded
function onHeaderLoad(){
  //Check if the log out button is pressed.
  checkSignOutButton();
  //Assign username on header
  assignUsernameOnHeader();
  //Check if the publish button is pressed
  checkPublishButton();
}

//Check if the log out button is pressed.
function checkSignOutButton(){
  var signoutButton = document.getElementById("logout_button");
  signoutButton.onclick = function(){
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
     window.location = "login.html";
    }, function(error) {
     alert(error);
    });
  }
}

//Check if the publish button is pressed
function checkPublishButton(){
  var publish_button = document.getElementById("publish_button");
  publish_button.onclick = postNewEvent();
}

//Assign username on header
function assignUsernameOnHeader(){
  //Check if a user is logged in.
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      var username = document.getElementById('username');
      var username_obtained;
      //Get the name of the user.
      if (user!=null) {
        username_obtained = user.displayName;
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong.");
      }
      //Assign it to the header. 
      username.innerHTML = username_obtained;
      //If the user is not logged in, 
      //returns it to the login page.
    } else {
      window.location = "login.html";
    }
  });
}

//Post a new event into the firebase database
function postNewEvent(){
  //Check if a user is logged in.
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    //Declare firebase data-base
    var database = firebase.database();        
    //Get user's id
    var user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    //Get user's total event created counter
    return database.ref('users/' +    user_id).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      return snapshot.val().total_event_created;
}).then(function(counter) {
      //Increase the total_event_counter by one
      var counter = counter +1;
      database.ref('users/'+user_id+'/total_event_created').set(counter);  
      //Get input from form
      var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
      console.log('title', title);
      var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
      var hour = document.getElementById("hour").value;
      var place = document.getElementById("place").value;
      var brief_description =    document.getElementById("brief_description").value;
      var detailed_description = document.getElementById("detailed_description").value;
      var contact_email = document.getElementById("contact_email").value;
      var contact_phone_number = document.getElementById("contact_phone_number").value;
      var imageUrl = document.getElementById("imageUrl").value; 
      //Post event into firebase database
      database.ref('events/' + user_id + '/' +  counter).set({
        title: title,
        date: date,
        hour: hour,
        place: place,
        brief_description: brief_description,
        detailed_description: detailed_description,
        contact_email: contact_email,
        contact_phone_number: contact_phone_number,
        imageUrl: imageUrl
      });
    });              
  });
}
```

La línea que dice console.log('title',title) de la función postNewEvent() es la que me devuelve la cadena vacía. Y ese en ese lugar del programa donde debería recibir los valores del input.

Answer (score 1):

Cosas que veo en tu código que me resultan un poco raras, a ver si vamos averiguando que sucede...

0 - Tienes un lio de scripts en cabecera terrible, veo tanto un **CND** de jQuery como el archivo de forma local, es muy recomendable que los scripts siempre los coloques antes de la etiqueta que cierra el body */body* para tu correcta interación con el DOM.

1 - He probado tu código en [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/?html,output) y me indica efectivamente que la función **onHeaderLoad()** no esta definida.

2 - Para usar firebase en la Web  necesitas el script que te proporcionan colocado en algún lugar de la estructura de tu js [Firebase Web GET STARTED](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

3 - Tienes la función **postNewEvent()** fuera del **$(document).ready...** prueba a introducirla dentro de la misma si estas accediendo a elementos del DOM, sobre todo porque tienes los scripts en cabecera y cargan antes que la propia estructura de tu HTML.

4 - Tienes el código un poco desestructurado y cuesta seguir su lógica, releelo y poco a poco observa donde puedes simplificar algunos bloques de tu código (que se puede hacer)

5 - Si vas a usar ***jQuery*** en tu proyecto pues estaría bien que para acceder a los elementos del DOM, sobre todo por legibilidad, uses sus funciones para realizar el acceso al DOM y su manejo y no mezclarlo con Javascript puro. *(Te ayudará tanto a ti para escribir el código como para seguir la lógica de tu programa a otros programadores).*

6 - Desde hace un tiempo no hace falta indicar el **"type"** y el **"language"** como atributos en los scripts de javascript, con solo indicar la ruta **"src"** es suficiente.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta tan detallada. Estoy comenzando a programar con lenguajes de desarrollo web y todavía estoy en lo de acostumbrarme al formato. Te cuento que me carga todo muy bien cuando lo ejecuto y incluso se crea el evento y todo dentro de la base de datos de firebase. El problema es que el input lo lee como string vacíos. Estoy implementando todo lo que me recomendaste a mi código. La inicialización de la base de datos la tengo en el app.js. ¿Entonces me dijiste que de las declaraciones de jquery del encabezado solo necesito una y que si es posible las mueva al </body>?

Comment: Por cierto, actualicé el código arriba. Fue que me faltó añadir una de las funciones.

Answer (score 0):

creo que en la recuperación del valor de entrada falta .value, de la siguiente forma :

En el script recuperar de la siguiente manera :

```
var dat=  document.getElementById("title").value;
alert(dat);
```

Comment: Hola Cristian_Meza. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. mira [answer] para mejorar la calidad de tus respuestas. Un saludo